# how to make a Simple Range Picker in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, range

I want to create a custom range picker where users can select start and end days from the given choices. The layout and the data I will be receiving from API is such that I can't use any jquery/javascript datepicker plugins. Also, its very simple.

The basic concept is this,
Let's say, there are 10 choices (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).

If the user clicks on 3, its the start of the range. And on second click, let's say user picks, 8, its the end of the range. A very basic range picker.

```
<div class="range_container">
   <div class="day">Day 1</div>
   <div class="day">Day 2</div>
   <div class="day selected start-day">Day 3</div> <!-- If User Picks 3, add "selected" and "start-day" class-->
   <div class="day">Day 4</div>
   <div class="day">Day 5</div>
   <div class="day">Day 6</div>
   <div class="day">Day 7</div>
   <div class="day selected end-day">Day 8</div><!-- User Picks 8, same as start date -->
   <div class="day">Day 9</div>
   <div class="day">Day 10</div>
   </div>
```

How can I achieve this with jquery?. However I try to google for answers, the results always lead to a date range picker which is not what I'm looking. Please help! Any links to tutorials or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `click` event handler to check what dates have already been selected and add/remove classes accordingly. Check it out, also see the code comments:

```js
$('.day').click(function(){
  if($('.start-day').length<1){//Start date not already selected
    $(this).addClass('selected');    
    $(this).addClass('start-day');
  }else if($('.end-day').length<1){//End date not already selected
    if($(this).index()<=$('.start-day').index()) return 0;//Check if end date is after start date
    $(this).addClass('selected');    
    $(this).addClass('end-day');    
  }else{//Start and end date already selected
    $('.day').removeClass('selected start-day end-day');
    $(this).addClass('selected');    
    $(this).addClass('start-day');
  }
});
```

```css
.start-day{
  color:green;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.end-day{
  color:red;  
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="range_container">
   <div class="day">Day 1</div>
   <div class="day">Day 2</div>
   <div class="day selected start-day">Day 3</div> <!-- If User Picks 3, add "selected" and "start-day" class-->
   <div class="day">Day 4</div>
   <div class="day">Day 5</div>
   <div class="day">Day 6</div>
   <div class="day">Day 7</div>
   <div class="day selected end-day">Day 8</div><!-- User Picks 8, same as start date -->
   <div class="day">Day 9</div>
   <div class="day">Day 10</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I will definitely tryout the solutions suggested by Kishan and Thai-Duong-Nguyen but for now, this is the best option for me as I need to rush on this project. It was also what I was trying to do in my code but couldn't get my head around it. Thanks @Theodore K.

Comment: @Kanchan, glad I helped. Fixed a mistake, replaced `break` with `return 0` which caused an exception.

Comment: @KanchanRai, please remember to always upvote the helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

here is the exact solution what you are looking for http://nitinhayaran.github.io/jRange/demo/

you just need to customize according to your need.

Comment: if you need help how to customize then just tell me i will send you the whole code that i use in my project

Comment: if you use above jRange then for min value and max value please use this variable ** min:$(".price-range-min").text(),
        max :$(".price-range-max").text() ** in jquery .. i took 1 whole day to customizing it.

Comment: for js file please refer [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ikishan/075qLmo9/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Kishan for the help! And for the pointers to help save time! As I was looking for a solution without any external plugins, I will opt for Theodore's solution but for the next stage of this project, I might have to go with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array and an event listener attached to each of those day divs, listening for a click, that adds to an array, assuming the array length is less than 2. For example:

```js
const range = [];
const dayDivs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("day"));
dayDivs.forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (range.length < 2) range.push(div.textContent);
}));
```

Then you have an array called 'range' that has your start and end days.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thai-Duong Nguyen, this looks like an interesting solution. I will try this out for sure.